# Calculating time offsets

Tags: time

I have a requirement to send an email at 8am to my users.

Every 30 mins the server fires a function

All the function knows is current time, and the goal is to query a database of users with defined timezone offsets (i.e. their local time offset relative to UTC)

I'm finding it difficult to reason because some timezones are +12, -12 and there's even +13/+14 utc offsets, so 8am in a +14 utc offset timezone is also 8am in a -10 offset timezone.

Here's a simplistic version

```
function getUTCOffsetAtTime(time, utcHour) {
  return time - utcHour
}

console.log('At 12am UTC: ' + getUTCOffsetAtTime(8, 0)) // +8 ✔️ 12am utc is 8am in a +8 offset timezone
console.log('At 1am UTC: ' + getUTCOffsetAtTime(8, 1)) // +7 ✔️
console.log('At 8am UTC: ' + getUTCOffsetAtTime(8, 8)) // +0 ✔️
console.log('At 9am UTC: ' + getUTCOffsetAtTime(8, 9)) // -1 ✔️
console.log('At 1pm UTC: ' + getUTCOffsetAtTime(8, 13)) // -5 ✔️
console.log('At 3pm UTC: ' + getUTCOffsetAtTime(8, 15)) // -7 ✔️
console.log('At 6pm UTC: ' + getUTCOffsetAtTime(8, 18)) // -10 ❌ should be -10 & +14
console.log('At 8pm UTC: ' + getUTCOffsetAtTime(8, 20)) // -12 ❌ should be -12 & +12
console.log('At 9pm UTC: ' + getUTCOffsetAtTime(8, 21)) // -13 ❌ should be +11
console.log('At 11pm UTC: ' + getUTCOffsetAtTime(8, 23)) // -15 ❌ should be +9
```

Comment: What kind of server is it? Do you have cron available or maybe windows task planner?

Comment: @RobertHarvey you can see +13 & +14 there above -11 & -10, they are valid offsets

Comment: In any case, the math should be the same.  What are you finding confusing?

Comment: @cyberbrain it's on a firebase scheduled cloude function https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_pubsub_#schedule

Comment: @RobertHarvey I updated my answer with a simplistic function that's failing

Answer (score 0):

Solving my own answer in JS - opted to do things in minutes rather than hours

```
function getUTCOffsetAtTime(time, utcHour, minutes = 0) {
  const basicOffset = hoursToMinutes(time - utcHour) - minutes
  const offset24 = hoursToMinutes(24) + basicOffset
  return [basicOffset, offset24].filter(
    o => o >= hoursToMinutes(-12) && o <= hoursToMinutes(14)
  )
}

const hoursToMinutes = hours => hours * 60
```